# How to change the ribbon groups dynamically based on the mdi child form?

Tags: winforms, devexpress, mdi, mdichild, mdiparent

I have a base form with devexpress ribbon control and an xtratabbedmdimanager with one datagridview in one of the tabs. Double-clicking the datagrid row, opens new tab form.

Is it possible when opening the new mdi child form to change the ribbon groups? Hide one ribbon group and appear a new one based on the mdi child form in the tab?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This should be happening automatically if you are assigning the ribbon groups to the child form and not the parent.  Ribbon groups from the parent should show all of the time, and when you switch from one child form to the other, only the ribbon items for that child form should show along side the parent groups.  Is this not happening?  I wonder if you can show a screen shot or two to make sure I understand.

Comment: By the way, this does presuppose that the `MdiMergeStyle` property on the parent ribbon is set to `Always`

Comment: I have used the ribbon and all its groups to the parent form and I am trying to switch over the visibility of each group based on the child forms. But I guess this is not the proper way since I am facing many difficulties.

Comment: @Hambone: You are right - I had to assign ribbon groups to the the child forms and the `MdiMergeStyle` property should be to `Always`. Please post it as an answer and I will accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Will do -- thanks.  I'm glad it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be happening automatically if you are assigning the ribbon groups to the child form and not the parent. Ribbon groups from the parent should show all of the time, and when you switch from one child form to the other, only the ribbon items for that child form should show along side the parent groups.

To enable this behavior, if it's not already done so, set the `MdiMergeStyle` property of the ribbon on the parent form to `Always`.